# How can I make a click able button in geojson.io table list?

Tags: web-mapping

How can I make a clickable button in geojson.io table list, that will be used in webGIS map (along with table features got from .geojson file), after clicking it will direct to another webpage.

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works